# mysql/php import csv into table with enclosures inside delimiter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, csv

I have come across a weird issue when importing a csv into mysql through sql or through php with data minipulation.

I have a csv from a third party (which i have no control of and i am unable to change) that is delimited by commas and has enclosures of double quotes. Simple enough. However in some of the cells there is data such as:

```
"first" value, secondvalue, thirdvalue, "fourth, value"
```

now when i import this into SQL the first value is being split due to the enclosure. How can i get it to ignore such cells and just input them as first value but still keep the enclosures so they work on "fourth, value" ?

Is there a regex that i could run on each line as i import it into the table (i dont mind importing lines one by one by reading them through php then using INSERT) or is there functionality in SQL to allow this?

I have tried the following statements but do not work

```
    load data local infile '../htdocs/invoice/upload/importthis.csv' 
    into table items_raw 
    fields terminated by ','  
    enclosed by '"' lines terminated by '\n'
    (date, clid_nu, clid, dnid, dcontext_nu, channel_nu,
    dstchannel_nu, lastapp_nu, lastdata_nu, duration, billsec_nu, disposition_nu, 
    amaflags_nu, accountcode_nu, uniqueid_nu, userfield_nu)
```

and have also tried using `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` however this also does not work

I have also tried using fgetcsv however i am getting the same results from it

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

so the regex `"((.*),(.*))"` seems to match the fourth value but not the first value. Is this the best way to go or am i over complicating this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like malformed CSV to me. This line *should be*:

```
"""first"" value", secondvalue, thirdvalue, "fourth, value"
```

where `"` is commonly used as an escape character.

The problem with using regexps on CSV input is that CSV is not a regular language.

Try using `fgetcsv`, see if that function has the same behavior as your SQL importer. Count the number of items it finds on each row. You might be able to catch all the anomalies that way.

Is it good enough to detect anomalies or do you also want to fix them automatically? - for instance if the number of anomalies is very high.

---

Alternatively you could write your own CSV parser that can read this, and convert the file to proper CSV.

Writing a CSV parser is actually not that hard. I can give an outline if you want.

Comment: apologies, was just editing to say that i have tried fgetcsv and i am getting the same problem. when you say CSV's are not a regular language is it a big mistake to use regex on them or is it still an acceptable solution?